# postgres query error for GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql

i have a table login_logout time which is like

```
id  user_id     start               end                      total(sec)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1   "2014-04-14 12:17:54.772"   "2014-04-14 12:17:55.772"   1
2   1   "2014-04-14 12:22:41.763"   "2014-04-14 12:31:14.295"   512
3   2   "2014-04-14 12:43:51.823"   "2014-04-14 12:48:40.706"   288
4   2   "2014-04-14 13:22:51.656"   "2014-04-14 13:22:52.656"   1
```

I want data in this format

```
    user : 1
------------------------------------------------------------------
        start_time      end_time    total (seconds)
        "12:17"         "12:17"         1
        "12:22"         "12:31"         512
                                    total:  513 
    user : 2
------------------------------------------------------------------
        "12:43"         "12:48"         288
        "13:22"         "13:22"         1
                                    total   289
```

But I am getting date in this format

```
user : 1
------------------------------------------------
start_time  end_time    total (seconds)
"12:17"     "12:17"     1
                total : 1
user : 1
------------------------------------------------
"12:22"     "12:31"     512
                total : 512

user : 2 
------------------------------------------------
"12:43"     "12:48"     288
                total : 288

user : 2 
------------------------------------------------
"13:22"      "13:22"    1
                total : 1
```

The query is :

```
SELECT l.user_id, 
      SUBSTR(cast (l.start::time as text), 1,5) startTime,
      SUBSTR(cast (l::time as text), 1,5) endTime,
       sum(total)
FROM   login_logout l 
GROUP  BY l.user_id, 
          starttime, 
          endtime
```

I understand that this is happening because of startTime,endTime added in group by clause.

When I remove it, I get famous '`must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`' error.

Can you please help in solving this?

Comment: So right now there are 2 records for each userid 1 & user id 2. I want only 2 records with sum of their time. You can check expected o/p given above.

Comment: do you want to select start time and end time? then you want show which start time and end time for the users

Comment: you can not get output in one line if you want to display both  start_time and end_time for one user.

Comment: start & end time group by user & total of (end time - start time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
select  l.user_id,  
SUBSTR(cast (min(l.stime)::time as text), 1,5) startTime,
SUBSTR(cast (max(l.etime)::time as text), 1,5) endTime,
sum(total) from login_logout l group by l.user_id
```

It Give Following ouptut:

```
   uid  startTime endTime  total

    1   12:17    12:31    513
    2   12:43     13:22    289
```

**OR**

```
select cast(uid as text) || '2' as ord, null as uid,'' as 
starttime,'' as endtime, sum(tse) from tt group by uid

union all

SELECT cast(uid as text) || '1' as ord, l.uid, 
      SUBSTR(cast (min(l.stime)::time as text), 1,5) startTime,
      SUBSTR(cast (max(l.etime)::time as text), 1,5) endTime,
       sum(tse)
FROM   tt l 
GROUP  BY l.uid, 
          l.stime, 
          l.etime order by ord
```

The `ord` column used for only order by

This Output Show like this

```
ord uid  startTime endTime  total
11   1     12:22     12:31   512
11   1     12:17     12:17     1
12                           513
21   2     13:22     13:22     1
21   2     12:43     12:48   288
22                           289
```

Comment: but the problem is that it is showing only 1 start & stop time whereas user logged in twice. Total time is correct but if u check the expected o/p then for user 1 it should show                    "12:17"  "12:17"  1
"12:22"  "12:31"  512

Comment: you want to show like this ah `"12:17"         "12:17"         1
        "12:22"         "12:31"         512
                                    total:  513 `

Comment: yes... right!!!... so the expected o/p should only be group by user. But to get start & end time I need to add it in group by clause. This group by is creating problem.

Comment: @user1298426 Now check it. its ok for you